# How to close all tabs with windows and terminals so I can quit

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

I have multiple tab pages. Some tab pages only have open files, some only have `:terminal`s open, and some have a mix of files and terminals.

At the end of the day, I want to quit Vim. Normally, I go through every tab page and close every window manually. But is there a better way? I tried `:wqa`, but that doesn't work because I have terminals running in some of my tab pages.

Comment: Older and more varied answers at SO's [What is the Vim command to quit all open windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14658600/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:qa!` to force vim to exit:

```
:qa[ll]!    Exit Vim.  Any changes to buffers are lost.
        Also see |:cquit|, it does the same but exits with a non-zero
        value.
```

As `:qa!` doesn't save buffer, you should use `:wqa` before that.

`:qa!` can be dangerous, a half-way stopped terminal might leave you garbage files.

You can also use `ls R` to list running terminal buffers and load them with `:b bufnr`.

Here is a command to list all running terminal buffers and modified readonly buffers in a new tab :

```
com ListUndead ListBuffers R =+
com -nargs=+ ListBuffers call s:list_buffers(<f-args>)

function s:list_buffers(...) abort

  let bufs = {}

  for flags in a:000
    let l = split( execute( printf('ls! %s', flags) ), "\n" )
    let l = map(l, { i,v -> matchstr(v, '\v^\s*\zs\d+') })
    for buf in l
      let bufs[ buf ] = buf
    endfor
  endfor

  let first = 1
  for buf in keys(bufs)
    if first
      exe 'tab sbuffer' buf
      let first = 0
    else
      exe 'sbuffer' buf
    endif
  endfor

endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to quit, but close all tabs, pick one and do `:tabonly` to keep it.